# Changing the color of output

Tags: java

I was trying to change the color of console output in java.As my program output displays a warning message so i thought to change that warning color.

After searching it over stackoverflow and response for similar questions I came accross Jansi and JLibs but they are not working.This is the sample code which i wrote using jansi.I included the jar in class-path

```
import static org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi.*;
import static org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi.Color.*;

class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
System.out.println( ansi().eraseScreen().fg(RED).a("Hello").fg(GREEN).a("       World").reset());
}
}
```

However its doing nothing just printing this: `←[2J←[31mHello←[32m World←[m`

I am using windows 7 and jdk 1.7 and i am not using eclipse.

Any help

Comment: Try running it from the command line.  It's unlikely that the IDE output windows will support console based codes

Comment: Windows 7, but what shell? Cygwin Bash may work.

Comment: i am running from command line only..

Comment: i am not aware about cygwin and how to use it to run java code

Comment: Also i am running my java code through ant script so i am not how cygwin can help me in this and plus it will add to one more requirement of cygwin

Comment: Not the Cygwin part, the bash part. bash is a shell that understands ANSI sequences. "Command line" does not. Your choice.

Answer (score 2):

from [Jansi](http://jansi.fusesource.org/)

> Using jansi is easy. Before you start sending ANSI escape sequences to
>   System.out make sure you run: `AnsiConsole.systemInstall();`

Comment: i have put this in java code and its showing exception that cannot find symbol

Comment: @Deepak add `import org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole` to your imports

Comment: The problem is not that the application sends wrong ANSI codes. There's nothing to render them as colors in the pipeline. Windows terminal does not do that.

Comment: @9000 I have tested it and it indeed does work on the Windows 7 command prompt http://imgur.com/e4dCWyv

Comment: @vandale: Great news! I wonder how do they do it under Windows.

Comment: @9000 from the [source](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi/blob/master/jansi/src/main/java/org/fusesource/jansi/WindowsAnsiOutputStream.java):  "A Windows ANSI escape processor, uses JNA to access native platform API's to change the console attributes."